# Adding two numbers given (digits in Linked List) using Strings

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I am trying to add two non negative numbers, the digits of which are stored in reverse order in two separate linked lists. The answer should also be a linked list with digits reversed and no trailing zeros.

I understand that there is a way to solve this question by adding digits and maintaining a carry each time, but I am trying to solve it by using addition operation on numbers.

Here's my code:

```
    /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * class ListNode {
     *     public int val;
     *     public ListNode next;
     *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; next = null; }
     * }
     */
    public class Solution {
        public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
            if(a==null || b==null){
                return null;


}
        String num1 = "";
        String num2 = "";
        ListNode temp1 = a;
        ListNode temp2 = b;
        while(temp1!=null){
            num1 = num1+Integer.toString(temp1.val);
            temp1 = temp1.next;
        }
        new StringBuilder(num1).reverse().toString();
        double value1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
        while(temp2!=null){
            num2 = num2+Integer.toString(temp2.val);
            temp2 = temp2.next;
        }
        new StringBuilder(num2).reverse().toString();
        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
        double result = value1+value2;
        String res = String.format("%.0f",result);
        ListNode first_node =  new ListNode(Character.getNumericValue(res.charAt(0)));
        ListNode ans  = first_node;
        for(int j=1;j<res.length();j++){
            ListNode node = new ListNode(Character.getNumericValue(res.charAt(j)));
            add(node,ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public void add(ListNode node, ListNode ans){
        ListNode temp;
        temp = ans;
        ans  = node;
        ans.next = temp;
    }
}
```

My code has been giving wrong answers. Can anyone point out the errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Aastik - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct and indirect.
You are trying to do big numbers arithmetics using floating point operations.
As a result - computing errors.

We have:

```
List<Integer> firstNumber;
List<Integer> secondNumber;
```

Lets **assume** `firstNumber > secondNumber`.

Try this alogrithm:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
int appendix = 0;
for (; i < secondNumber.size(); i++) {
    int sum = firstNumber.get(i) + secondNumber.get(i) + appendix;
    result.append(sum % 10);
    appendix = sum / 10;
}

for (; i < firstNumber.size(); i++) {
    int sum = firstNumber.get(i) + appendix;
    result.append(sum % 10);
    appendix = sum / 10;
}

if (appendix != 0) 
    result.append(appendix);

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your add function looks incorrect. You will get you number in the reverse order than what is expected.

Also, your solution is missing the point of the question. Your approach will fail if you have a number with a lot of digits (even double has its limits ~ 2^1024 I think). A linked list representation allows for numbers even bigger.

The correct solution would just iterate through both the lists simultaneously with a carry digit while creating the solution list. If this is a question in an assignment or coding competition, your solution would be judged wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` method is wrong, it doesn't build correctly the list. Here is how the final part of your method should look, without the `add` method:

```
for(int j=1;j<res.length();j++){
   ans.next = new ListNode(Character.getNumericValue(res.charAt(j)));;
   ans = ans.next;
}
return first_node;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, the variable ans is not updating. You can try this:

```
ans = add(node,ans);
```

and in your add method, change the method to return ListNode ans

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not straightforward and wouldn't give you expected results.

Here is a simple approach which wouldn't require much explanation as the addition is simple integer by integer.

Do note that i carry forward when the sum of two integers is greater than 9 else continue with the sum of next integers from both the list.

```
class Node {
    private Object data;
    private Node next;
    public Object getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(Object data) {  this.data = data; }
    public Node getNext() { return next; }
    public void setNext(Node next) { this.next = next; }
    public Node(final Object data, final Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Node:[Data=" + data + "]"; }
}


class SinglyLinkedList {
    Node start;
    public SinglyLinkedList() { start = null; }

    public void addFront(final Object data) {
        // create a reference to the start node with new data
        Node node = new Node(data, start);

        // assign our start to a new node
        start = node;
    }

    public void addRear(final Object data) {
        Node node = new Node(data, null);
        Node current = start;

        if (current != null) {
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(node);
        } else {
            addFront(data);
        }
    }

    public void deleteNode(final Object data) {
        Node previous = start;

        if (previous == null) {
            return;
        }

        Node current = previous.getNext();

        if (previous != null && previous.getData().equals(data)) {
            start = previous.getNext();
            previous = current;
            current = previous.getNext();
            return;
        }

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.getData().equals(data)) {
                previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                current = previous.getNext();
            } else {
                previous = previous.getNext();
                current = previous.getNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public Object getFront() {
        if (start != null) {
            return start.getData();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Node current = start;

        if (current == null) {
            System.out.println("SingleLinkedList is Empty");
        }

        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current);
            current = current.getNext();
            if (current != null) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;

        Node current = start;

        while (current != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public Node getStart() {
        return this.start;
    }

    public Node getRear() {
        Node current = start;
        Node previous = current;
        while (current != null) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return previous;
    }
}

public class AddNumbersInSinglyLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList listOne = new SinglyLinkedList();
        SinglyLinkedList listTwo = new SinglyLinkedList();
        listOne.addFront(5);
        listOne.addFront(1);
        listOne.addFront(3);
        listOne.print();
        System.out.println();
        listTwo.addFront(2);
        listTwo.addFront(9);
        listTwo.addFront(5);
        listTwo.print();
        SinglyLinkedList listThree = add(listOne, listTwo);
        System.out.println();
        listThree.print();
    }

    private static SinglyLinkedList add(SinglyLinkedList listOne, SinglyLinkedList listTwo) {
        SinglyLinkedList result = new SinglyLinkedList();
        Node startOne = listOne.getStart();
        Node startTwo = listTwo.getStart();
        int carry = 0;
        while (startOne != null || startTwo != null) {
            int one = 0;
            int two = 0;
            if (startOne != null) {
                one = (Integer) startOne.getData();
                startOne = startOne.getNext();
            }
            if (startTwo != null) {
                two = (Integer) startTwo.getData();
                startTwo = startTwo.getNext();
            }
            int sum = carry + one + two;
            carry = 0;
            if (sum > 9) {
                carry = sum / 10;
                result.addRear(sum % 10);
            } else {
                result.addRear(sum);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample Run

```
Node:[Data=3], Node:[Data=1], Node:[Data=5]
Node:[Data=5], Node:[Data=9], Node:[Data=2]
Node:[Data=8], Node:[Data=0], Node:[Data=8]
```